# AmazonLinux2 permission denied

Tags: permissions

I am using Amazon Linux 2. It was fine until I tried to upload my files to /html folder. It says permission denied and then I messed up with all /var/www/html folders. Then I got to know files can only go to root folders. However, when I tried to log in to amazon server it says permission denied even after chmod 400. I don't know what I am doing wrong.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AZGb.png)I messed up with lot of permissions and now I am unable to log in. Is there anything we can do to reset all commands ?

ramanpreetsingh@Ramanpreets-Air Downloads % chmod 400 2022SinghR.pem
ramanpreetsingh@Ramanpreets-Air Downloads % ssh -i 2022SinghR.pem ec2-user@3.98.225.49
hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys_foreach failed for /Users/ramanpreetsingh/.ssh/known_hosts: Permission denied
The authenticity of host '3.98.225.49 (3.98.225.49)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:ieeGn2R/3xwHp36vj1GiM2aDFQIJA4lM+1p070u95xM.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? no
Host key verification failed.
ramanpreetsingh@Ramanpreets-Air Downloads % chmod 777 2022SinghR.pem
ramanpreetsingh@Ramanpreets-Air Downloads % ssh -i 2022SinghR.pem ec2-user@3.98.225.49
hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys_foreach failed for /Users/ramanpreetsingh/.ssh/known_hosts: Permission denied
The authenticity of host '3.98.225.49 (3.98.225.49)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:ieeGn2R/3xwHp36vj1GiM2aDFQIJA4lM+1p070u95xM.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? no
Host key verification failed.
ramanpreetsingh@Ramanpreets-Air Downloads %

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to continue the connection?

[image]

If it persists, some solutions listed here might get you some help:
[Troubleshoot permission denied](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-fix-permission-denied-errors/)